# Show Test Ads In Editor

Tags: unity-game-engine

Can I show ads from **any ad network** inside the **Editor**?

If not, then how do I check that the request was succesful in **Editor**? You can give an example from any SDK.

Comment: If its google ads , it will show in Unity3d console message dummy ad loaded

Comment: Most commonly used are GoogleAds and UnityAds. Both have documentation on how you can test your ads in the Editor. However, my personal experience is that UnityAds is easier to setup and has a more clear indication that your test ads work from within the editor. This is because you get an actual test ad inside the Editor as opposed to Google.

Answer (score 1):

When using admob in the unity editor you can not actually view the real ad units or the test ad units. Unity will give you a log message saying that the ad was run, but it will not call the reward call back. You can implement platform specific code using

#if UNITY_EDITOR

your reward call back code goes here

#endif

this way you can trigger the reward call back in unity without watching the ad so the program will still function properly.
You must build the program to actually view the test ads and make sure all the callbacks are working.